# In GLFW app, std::cin behaves oddly

Tags: python, c++, opengl, glfw

I'm abusing OpenGL to make it render me single screenshots of an object at a variety of angles. I don't need the GUI to be interactive; I just need to be able to start it from the console and enter attitude information via `stdin`. I need it to work this way because it'll be called via `popen` from a Python application.

Unfortunately, when I use `std::cin` to accomplish this, giving it the `\n` character doesn't seem to cause it to register the input. Instead, I have to follow `\n` by Ctrl+D, which allows me to continue to provide additional input as expected.

Note that if I do Ctrl+D on the first input (the `qw`), it exits as you'd expect (due to `cin.eof()` coming up `true`).

That behavior would be acceptable, except [it appears Python won't allow me to send a Ctrl+D to the OpenGL app without closing the stream entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678620/trying-to-send-an-eof-signal-ctrld-signal-using-python-via-popen) (not what I want). I've also tried sending a [`curses.ascii.EOT`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.ascii.html) (the end-of-transmission character, 0x04) instead ([per this forum question](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/525403-write-eof-without-closing)), but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here's the relevant code:

```
  glfwSwapBuffers(window);

  std::cerr << "Waiting for input ? " << std::flush;

  // priming read
  std::cin >> qw;

  /*
   * Main event loop
   */
  while (!std::cin.eof()) {

    //glfwPollEvents(); // Seems to make no difference

    std::cin >> qx;  
    std::cin >> qy;
    std::cin >> qz;

    object = glm::normalize(glm::dquat(qw, qx, qy, qz));
    std::cerr << "Quaternion: " << object.w << ',' << object.x << ',' << object.y << ',' << object.z << std::endl;

    scene.render(&shader_program, object, translation, sensor);
    pixels = scene.projected_area(width, height);
    projected_area = pixels * box_width * box_width / (double)(width * height);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(17) << projected_area << std::endl;

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    // next priming read
    std::cin >> qw;
  }

  glfwTerminate();
```

It seems as if this particular use-case is outside what people usually do with OpenGL. Can anyone explain what's happening / tell me how to make it behave as it would if I weren't using GLFW?

**Update:** I'm wondering if this might be happening because [glfw opens multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702778/c11-thread-multithreads-rendering-with-opengl-prevents-main-thread-reads-std/11112665#11112665). Even before I call *any* glfw methods, I see five threads for my process:

```
$ ls -l /proc/16051/task
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 7 mohawkjohn mohawkjohn 0 May 16 19:18 16051
dr-xr-xr-x 7 mohawkjohn mohawkjohn 0 May 16 19:18 16052
dr-xr-xr-x 7 mohawkjohn mohawkjohn 0 May 16 19:18 16053
dr-xr-xr-x 7 mohawkjohn mohawkjohn 0 May 16 19:18 16054
dr-xr-xr-x 7 mohawkjohn mohawkjohn 0 May 16 19:18 16055
```

**Update 2:** I've verified that the normal behavior occurs when I open a file and read from an `ifstream` instead of from standard in. I also noticed that when I hit enter in the console of the OpenGL app, the feedback I get is `^M` instead of a linefeed, even though I'm in Linux.

Comment: What makes you think that this is GLFW's fault? If you try this with a regular console app, does it work? Also, what OS are you using? Lastly, I don't think checking for EOF is generally the best way to handle continue input of this form.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why would this not work with a regular console app? The behavior of the `>>` operator on `cin` is defined by the C++ standard. I'm not sure how to respond to your statement about EOF, because I'm expressly trying to *not* use EOF for line endings; I'm only trying to use EOF to check for the end of the input, which is pretty standard usage.

Comment: Perhaps the input stream buffering was changed from line to buffer? Try an explicit `setvbuf` on `stdin` after setting up glfw.

Comment: @Cameron If that were the problem, wouldn't it be working correctly *before* `glfwInit()` gets called?

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk: Possibly, unless it's configured during a global object's construction (which runs before main). Have you tried it before calling `glfwInit()`?

Comment: @Cameron Yes, as described above (see "Update"). I've never used `setvbuf` before; what is the default setting?

Comment: The default is line buffered.

Comment: @Cameron No change in behavior. And it's still sending `^M` instead of enter for some reason. Uggh, so frustrating.

Comment: What makes you think that it's "abusing OpenGL" and that "people don't usually do this"? I use OpenGL for off-screen rendering all the time. The only difference is that I use GLUT (probably doesn't matter) and that I create a FBO instead of using the (hidden) window framebuffer. Try using an FBO and don't call `glfwSwapBuffers`.

Comment: @ybungalobill Why not `glfwSwapBuffers`? And I hadn't realized it was possible to render offscreen, though I suppose that's why we swap buffers after all. I'd searched a bit, too. Mind pointing me to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind people over at the [GLFW issue tracker](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1017#issuecomment-302119378) have provided an explanation for this behavior, which — it appears — is not actually caused by GLFW.

Somehow, my `stty` settings got borked (I'm still unclear how this happened). The resolution is to run

```
stty sane
```

prior to running my application. Note that the current settings of `stty` can be checked using

```
stty -a
```

In this case, the problem appears to have been that the `icrnl` setting was turned off; it normally converts carriage returns from the keyboard into linefeeds.